# Reload webview at speicific time

Tags: android, webview, timer, reload

I just started developing an android app and it has a webview on it. I was hoping to reload the webview every 15 minutes starting at specific time and if I understand correctly, I need to use AlarmManager in order to accomplish this. But I'm not really getting how to use AlarmManager so could someone help me with this? Maybe little example or something?

Thanks!

Also, FYI I have looked at the documentations.

**UPDATE**
so I've tried to implement AlarmManager here.. and don't think it's working...
here's my Activity file...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// to make our alarm manager
AlarmManager alarmManager;
WebView myWebView;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

Context context;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.context = this;

    //initialize alarm manager
    //alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    // create instance of a calendar
    //Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    // create an intent to Alarm Receiver class
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this.context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("<some url goes in here>");
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    reloadWebView();
}
private void reloadWebView(){
    AlarmManager alarmManger = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval = 1000*60*15;

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);

    alarmManger.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);

    }
}
```

and here's the AlarmReceiver class
    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
    WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        myWebView.reload();
        Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong...?
Thank you!

Comment: http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You schedule alarm manager to fire your intent at 4am. 
With RTC_WAKEUP use current system time + interval for first fire:

```
alarmManger.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + interval, interval, pendingIntent);
```

Also check that your alarm receiver is registered in Manifest

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :D
However, I need my app to first fire intent at a specific time not at whenever the app starts or device reboots. And I'm more curious of how to grab my webview (that reload in my code crashes app :'( ) and reload it from AlarmReceiver class.